# c# MVVM hide buttons that you've clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've a homework for a hangman game. I'd like in the buttonFunction or somewhere else, the button I've pressed to come Hidden and so on the next time and next.

**MainWindow:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="59*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="55*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="68*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="65*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="72*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="13*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="34*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}" CommandParameter="a">
        a
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}" CommandParameter="b">
        b
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}" CommandParameter="c">
        c
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}" CommandParameter="d">
        d
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}" CommandParameter="e">
        e
    </Button>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DisplayWordInTextbox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindowViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace test.ViewModel
{
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string[] words;
    private string currentWord;
    private string copyCurrentWord;

    private string displayWordInTextbox;
    public string DisplayWordInTextbox
    {
        get
        {
            return displayWordInTextbox;
        }
        set
        {
            displayWordInTextbox = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DisplayWordInTextbox");
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        buttonClick = new RelayCommand(buttonFunction);
        loadWordsFromFile();
        selectWord();
        displayWord();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    private ICommand buttonClick;
    public ICommand ButtonClick
    {
        get
        {
            return buttonClick;
        }
        set
        {
            buttonClick = value;
        }
    }

    void buttonFunction(object obj)
    {
        string buttonContent = obj.ToString();

        if (currentWord.Contains(buttonContent) || currentWord.Contains(buttonContent.ToUpper()))
        {
            char[] temp = copyCurrentWord.ToCharArray();
            char[] findWord = currentWord.ToCharArray();
            char guessChar = buttonContent.ElementAt(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < findWord.Length; i++)
            {
                if (findWord[i] == guessChar || findWord[i] == Char.ToUpper(guessChar))
                {
                    temp[i] = findWord[i];
                }
            }
            copyCurrentWord = new string(temp);
            displayWord();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(buttonContent + " isn't found!");
        }
    }

    private void loadWordsFromFile()
    {
        words = new string [] {"cat", "dog"};
    }

    private void selectWord()
    {
        int randomWordIndex = (new Random()).Next(words.Length);
        currentWord = words[randomWordIndex];
        char[] currentWordArray = currentWord.ToArray();
        bool isWord = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < currentWord.Length; i++)
        {
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
            {
                if (currentWordArray[i] == c || currentWordArray[i] == Char.ToUpper(c))
                {
                    isWord = true;
                }
            }
            if (isWord == true)
            {
                copyCurrentWord += "_";
                isWord = false;
            }
            else
            {
                copyCurrentWord += currentWordArray[i];
            }
        }
        words = words.Where(w => w != words[randomWordIndex]).ToArray();
    }

    private void displayWord()
    {
        DisplayWordInTextbox = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < copyCurrentWord.Length; i++)
        {
            DisplayWordInTextbox += copyCurrentWord.Substring(i, 1);
            DisplayWordInTextbox += " ";
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want the button to become **invisible** when clicked? Because the default behavior with command binding is that a button becomes **inactive** when the command's `CanExecute()` returns `false`. Then you wouldn't need any extra properties in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Visibility property for each button

**.xaml

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}" Visibility="{Binding MyProperty}" CommandParameter="a">
        a
</Button>
```

**.cs

```
private Visibility myProperty
public Visibility MyProperty
{
   get {return myProperty;}
   set {myProperty = value;NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");}
}
```

and in your Command, you can switch the visibility. Something like that:

```
void buttonFunction(object obj)
{
   switch(obj.ToString())
   {
      case "a": 
         MyPropertyA = Visibility.Hidden;
         MyPropertyB = Visibility.Visible;
         break;
      case "b": 
         MyPropertyB = Visibility.Hidden;
         break;
         ....
   }
   ....
}
```

Comment: when I do that all of my buttons go Hidden, not only the clicked one

Comment: You must create property for each button.

Comment: and who could I know which property has to be activated in the buttonFunction?